# Compare two List sorted

Tags: list, haskell, merge, compare

I have this codec but, it shows no repeated elements, why?

```
cosinesim :: Ord a => [(a,Float)] -> [(a,Float)] -> [(a,Float,Float)]
cosinesim a b = go a b
    where
       go [] b = map (\l -> (fst l, 0, snd l)) b
       go a [] = map (\l -> (fst l, snd l, 0)) a
       go a@((x,n):t) b@((y,m):r) = case compare x y of
           LT -> (x,n,0) : go t b
           EQ -> (x,n,m) : go t r
           GT -> (y,0,m) : go a r
```

Input : Two list sorted.

List1= `[(["variety"], 4.50),(["vegetable"], 3.50),(["velvet"], 2.50)]`

List2= `[(["variety"], 4.50),(["ve"], 3.50),(["velvet"], 2.50)]`

Output :

`[(["variety"], 4.50, 4.50 ), (["vegetable"], 3.50, 0), (["velvet"], 2.50 2.50) ,(["ve"], 0, 3.50)]`

My question is because only show the element that repeat in two list, because what I want is that all elements appear.

Comment: What is it supposed to do?

Comment: I have two lists. And the first list compared with the second.
If the item exists in the second list makes me a (Item 5.5)
If only it exists in the first list (Element 5.0)
If only exists in the second list (Item 0.5). But only it shows me the repeated elements.

Comment: What are `Item 5.5`, `Element 5.0`, and `Item 0.5`?

Comment: is (string, Float, Float) where String depend of de list that exists. Float is value calculate in other operation.

Comment: I have simplified the problem to see if it operates more simply.

Comment: Can you provide some sample input and write what you want the output to be?

Comment: Input `List1=[(["variety"], 4.50),(["vegetable"], 3.50),(["velvet"], 2.50)]`   `List2= [(["variety"], 4.50),(["ve"], 3.50),(["velvet"], 2.50)]`   
Output = ` [(["variety"], 4.50, 4.50 ), (["vegetable"], 3.50, 0), (["velvet"], 2.50 2.50) ,(["ve"], 0, 3.50) `

Comment: Can you add that to your question?  The formatting is messed up in a comment and it's much easier to read with full markdown.

Comment: I have a hard time understanding this question. My guess is: if the first list contains `(x,y1)` and the second `(x,y2)`, generate `(x,y1,y2)` Otherwise, if the first contains `(x,y1)` but no `(x,_)` is in the second, generate `(x,y1,0)`. Further, for those `(x,y2)` in the second list without any `(x,_)` in the first, generate `(x,0,y2)`. This is basically what a `FULL OUTER JOIN` does in SQL, I think, except that we use `0` instead of `NULL`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to combine the elements of both lists, keeping the keys unique I would recommend using a `Map` from `Data.Map`.  You can then combine two maps using `union`, `unionWith`, or `unionWithKey`.  The second one will be more useful here, though.  Since you also want to indicate when a value is from the first or second list only using `0`, it would be better to have a data type that represents that explicitly:

```
import qualified Data.Map as M

data Those a b
    = This a        -- Only left
    | Those a b     -- Both
    | That b        -- Only right
    deriving (Eq, Show)

this :: a -> Those a b -> a
this def (This a)    = a
this def (Those a b) = a
this def _           = def

that :: b -> Those a b -> b
that def (That b)    = b
that def (Those a b) = b
that def _           = def

-- Give this a better name than Items
type Items k = M.Map k (Those Float Float)
```

This just sets up a couple types and tools that we'll use later.  The `Those` type represents left, right, or both, and the `this` and `that` combinators help us extract values from them easily, just like the `maybe` combinator in `Prelude`.

```
listToLeftItems :: Ord a => [(a, Float)] -> Items a
listToLeftItems = M.fromList . map (fmap This)

listToRightItems :: Ord a => [(a, Float)] -> Items a
listToRightItems = M.fromList . map (fmap That)

cosinesim :: Ord a => [(a, Float)] -> [(a, Float)] -> [(a, Float, Float)]
cosinesim left right
    = map (\(key, those) -> (key, this 0 those, that 0 those))
    $ M.toList
    $ M.unionWith go (listToLeftItems left)
                     (listToRightItems right)
    where
        go leftVal rightVal = case (leftVal, rightVal) of
            (This a, That b) -> Those a b
            (x, y) -> y  -- We know we won't have any other combinations,
                         -- this just keeps the compiler from throwing a warning
```

The `listToLeftItems` just applies `This` to every `Float` in the list, then converts it to a `Map`, and similarly for `listToRightItems`.  Now your function just converts the input lists to `Map`s, unions them using `go` (which I think is simple enough to understand), converts back to a list, then flattens out the `(a, Those Float Float)` to `(a, Float, Float)`.  It gives you the results you want, but not in the same order.  You can use this as a basis for getting it in the order you want, if that matters.